# Let $f(x)=x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ Then show $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } L(f,P_n)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } U(f,P_n)=\dfrac {1} {2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

- Integrate  $f(x)=x$ for $x\in [0,1]$.

Let $P_n=\left\{ \left[ 0,\dfrac {1}{n}\right],\left[ \dfrac {1}{n},\dfrac {2}{n}\right] ,\ldots ,\left[ 1-\dfrac {1}{n},1\right] \right\}$ be partition of $[0,1]$. Then, $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } L(f,P_n)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } U(f,P_n)=\dfrac {1} {2}$.

**My question is** how did writer find this $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } L(f,P_n)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } U(f,P_n)=\dfrac {1} {2}$? Can you explain?

I tried something for my question:

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } L(f,P_n)=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \sum ^{n}_{i=1}m_{i}\Delta _{i}= \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \sum ^{n}_{i=1}\sup \left\{ f\left( x\right) :x\in \left[ x_{i-1},x_{i}\right] \right\}(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

So,hence how can I find $\dfrac {1} {2}$ from this?

Comment: $x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $sup\, \{f(x) : x\in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\} = \frac{i}{n} $, now evaluate the limit

Comment: The sum of the first $n-1$ numbers is $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$. The sum the first $n$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Then use l'Hôpital.

Comment: @Adam Thanks but how did you find $\dfrac {i} {n}$? I couldn't.

Comment: Your $x_i$ is $\frac{i}{n}$

Comment: @Adam that is, you say that $f(x_i)=\dfrac {i} {n}$, why? I couldn't see. Can you explain?

Comment: $f(x)=x \implies f(x_i)=f(\frac{i}{n})=x_i=\frac{i}{n}$

Comment: the maximum value of $f$ on $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ is $x_{i}$ since your function is increasing and continuous